# Comparing 2 strings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nstask

I have a `NSTask` of which the output is stored in an `NSData` object. From this I get a string via

`NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Now I can `NSLog` this string and then compare it via `[outputString isEqualToString:@"NSLogged String"]`. The result is that the two strings are not identical. Why is that? I played with the encoding but this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: could you show us the `outputString`?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya This is what I copied from Xcode's output terminal: /usr/bin/python

Comment: If your copied string is `/usr/bin/python` then you should use `[outputString isEqualToString:@"/usr/bin/python"]`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Just put in a placeholder in the question and not the exact string. This is of course what I do.

Comment: @DaPhil: Perhaps the string read from the task contains a trailing newline? - Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"output='%@', outputString)` ?

Comment: a little correction in *Martin R*'s comment, `NSLog(@"output='%@'", outputString)`. Added closing `"`.

Comment: My I ask, why you store the output in a NSData object?

Comment: @Flovdis: Reading from the process started by NSTask is probably done with a NSFileHandle, and that returns the data as NSData objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from your tool contains a trailing newline character. So either compare against
`"yourExpectedString\n"` or use something like

```
outputString = [outputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
```

to remove the newline characters.